# I want to pass array in ajax call

Tags: arrays, ajax

Here is my code

```
var itemDetail = [];    
itemDetail[362] = {'qty':2}
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: {update_cart_action:'update_qty',cart:itemDetail},
        success: function(msg){


        }
    });
```

i want to pass array like this

```
Array(
     [362]=>array(
          ['qty']=>2
      )
)
```

Array is pass but its not passing the correct way in console its shows like this

```
update_cart_action:update_qty
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
..........
cart[362][qty]:2
```

but i want to pass like this

```
update_cart_action:update_qty
cart[362][qty]:2
```

How can i do this?
is this possible to In GET method pass array?

**EDIT**

I am trying solution

```
var itemDetail[id] = {};
```

than this give me error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

another without using var

```
itemDetail[id] = {};
```

than this give me error itemDetail is undefined

another try

```
var itemDetail = [];
itemDetail[id] = {};
```

than this is also give me this type of array

```
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
cart[]:
..........
cart[362][qty]:2
```

Answer (score 1):

That is what javascript does. Its not a problem for the back end, you will receive it like

```
cart[362][qty]:2
```

You can try using objects, not arrays.

Comment: How can i pass objects

Comment: The data you are sending is an object. So just provide a key and a value (which is going to be an object). The idea is that you wont have all of those empty key/value pairs in the object. For example: `var itemDetail = {}; itemDetail.362 = {}; itemDetail.362.qty = 2;` and you pass the itemDetail object.

Comment: in my array 362 is not fixed i am getting that input value so how can i create that object

Comment: i am trying to like this `var id = 365` `itemDetail.id.qty = 2;` but its not give me 365 value so how can i create that object

Comment: Try it like this `itemDetails[id] = {}; itemDetails[id].qty = 2`. I tested it and it worked fine.

Comment: edit `var itemDetail = []; ` to become `var itemDetail = {};` this